# Jquery parent not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

A few days ago I created a comment system (hardly) , and I wanted to add the `Edit`, `Reply`, and `Delete` function, and after searching the web (including this one) I managed , but now I have a problem with jQuery. I want to use it in order to create some buttons that when clicked will display the `Reply`, `Delete` and `Edit` form, so I've search this forum and find some solutions, and applied them, but I have various problems:

First is that when I use `.toggle`, it will display a form for all comments , then I started to use `parents()`, but when I use this nothing works!

**Here is the code:**

```
<body>
    <h1>Comments (3)</h1>

    <div class="comment">
        <form action="new.php" id="new_comment" method="post" name=
        "new_comment">
            <textarea class="text_cmt" name="text_cmt" placeholder=
            "Post a new comment">
</textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Post">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="comment">
        <span class="author">Guest</span><br>
        hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br>
        <span class="date">Posted: Sep 27, 2015 | 12:55:48</span><br>
        <span class="replies">[+] 1 replies</span><span class="replies"></span>

        <form action="delete.php" id="delete" method="post" name="delete">
            <input id="password" name="password" placeholder=
            "Password to delete" type="text"><input type="submit" value=
            "Delete">
        </form><input class="replytopic" name="send" type="submit" value=
        "Reply"><button class="button2">Edit</button><button class=
        "button3">Delete</button>

        <div id="reply">
            <form action="reply.php" class="reply" id="new_comment" method=
            "post" name="new_comment">
                <input name="par_code" type="hidden" value="ySWxTshchM">
                <textarea class="text_cmt" name="text_cmt" placeholder=
                "Reply to Guest">
</textarea><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Reply">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="children">
            <form action="edit.php" id="edit" method="post" name="edit">
                <textarea class="text_cmt" name="text_cmt">
</textarea><br>
                <input id="password" name="password" placeholder=
                "Password to edit" type="text"><input type="submit" value=
                "Edit">
            </form>

            <div class="child">
                <span class="author">k86k</span><br>
                gstrdynbv<br>
                <span class="date">Posted: Sep 25, 2015 | 00:00:00</span><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="comment">
        <span class="author">Guest</span><br>
        jjjjj<br>
        <span class="date">Posted: Sep 27, 2015 | 12:41:11</span><br>
        <span class="replies">[+] 1 replies</span><span class="replies"></span>

        <form action="delete.php" id="delete" method="post" name="delete">
            <input id="password" name="password" placeholder=
            "Password to delete" type="text"><input type="submit" value=
            "Delete">
        </form><input class="replytopic" name="send" type="submit" value=
        "Reply"><button class="button2">Edit</button><button class=
        "button3">Delete</button>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
$(function() {
    $(".replytopic").on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().next(".reply").toggle();
    });
})
</script>
<script>
$( ".button3" ).click(function() {
    $( "form#delete" ).toggle();
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".replytopic").on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().next("form#reply").toggle();
    });
})
</script>
```

Here is a demonstration of what is happening with my show/hide: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3o8hr40/8/)
and also I want to mention that this page is generated by index.php:

```
<?php
get_comments('1234');
?>

<script>
$(function() {
    $(".replytopic").on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().next(".reply").toggle();
    });
})
</script>
<script>
$( ".button3" ).click(function() {
    $( "form#delete" ).toggle();
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".replytopic").on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().next("form#reply").toggle();
    });
})
</script>
```

and my PHP [functions.php](http://jsfiddle.net/1do4t8aj/)

Comment: You have multiple ids on page, that's one problem...

Comment: I could add their unique id from the database... but that would be no use because then I don't know how to add that identifier inside the java code

Comment: what a mess. it seems you don't know what `$.next` does, also you have no form with id of reply, so this doesn't work `("form#reply")`. I hope those tips at least help a bit, goodluck! (using the same `id` multiple times is not kosher, but it's not causing problems here)

Comment: Would help to scale the html down in the question to minimal code needed to represent an individual problem. For example start with getting buttons working. That doesn't require any text. For repeating elements show 2 not 3 or more. your html is pretty ugly and it's much harder to help when the same ugliness is repeated more than is needed to create a minimal example of the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to not have same-name `id` values so those all need to be switched to `class` instead. You should also try wrapping your delete form so you can easily traverse up from the clicked button to a containing element. I did the delete button specifically, so if there are any other issues, you should be able to apply the same principles.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0oky70dd/

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/* comments */
.comment {
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 7px 23px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
}
.child {
    width: calc(100% - 92px);
    height: auto;
    padding: 3px 25px;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 35px;
    box-shadow: -5px 0px 0px 0px #777;
    background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.05);
    border: 1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.1);
}
/* fonts */
.author, .date {
    font-size: 11.2px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #777;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.replies {
    color: #39C;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.replies:hover {
    color: #39F;
}
.text_cmt {
    width: calc(100% - 22px);
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.3);
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
h1 {
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#hide {
}
#children {
}
#item {
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
button.edittopic {
    float: right;
    color: white;
    background-color: #3cb0fd;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
button.button2 {
    background-color: #2FC332;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 0px none;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}
button.delete_button {
    background-color: #D60202;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 0px none;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}
form.form_delete {
    width: 35.5%;
    display: none;
}
form#edit {
    display: none;
}
form.reply {
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".edittopic").on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().next(".reply").toggle();
    });

    $( ".delete_button" ).click(function() {
        $(this).parents(".delete_wrapper").find(".form_delete").toggle();
    });

    $(".edittopic").on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().next("form#reply").toggle();
    });
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Comments (3)</h1>
<div class="comment">
    <form action="new.php" method="post" enctpye="" name="new_comment">
        <textarea class="text_cmt" name="text_cmt" placeholder="Post a new comment"></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
</div>
<div class="comment" name="ySWxTshchM"><span class="author">Guest</span><br />
    hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br />
    <span class="date">Posted: Sep 27, 2015 | 12:55:48</span><br />
    <span class="replies">[+] 1 replies</span><span class="replies">Reply</span>
    <div class="delete_wrapper">
        <form action="delete.php" method="post" enctpye="" class="form_delete">
            <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password to delete" id="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </form>
        <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="replytopic" name="send" />
        <button class="button2">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete_button">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div id="reply">
        <form class="reply" action="reply.php" method="post" enctpye="" name="new_comment">
            <input type="hidden" name="par_code" value="ySWxTshchM" />
            <textarea class="text_cmt" name="text_cmt" placeholder="Reply to Guest"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Reply" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div name="children" id="children">
        <form action="edit.php" method="post" enctpye="" id="edit">
            <textarea class="text_cmt" name="text_cmt"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password to edit" id="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
        </form>
        <div class="child" name="tsrdyj5645w3"><span class="author">k86k</span><br />
            gstrdynbv<br />
            <span class="date">Posted: Sep 25, 2015 | 00:00:00</span><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="comment" name="F6aBYrq5wG"><span class="author">Guest</span><br />
    jjjjj<br />
    <span class="date">Posted: Sep 27, 2015 | 12:41:11</span><br />
    <span class="replies">[+] 1 replies</span><span class="replies">Reply</span>
    <div class="delete_wrapper">
        <form action="delete.php" method="post" enctpye="" class="form_delete">
            <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password to delete" id="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </form>
        <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="replytopic" name="send" />
        <button class="button2">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete_button">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div id="reply">
        <form class="reply" action="reply.php" method="post" enctpye="" name="new_comment">
            <input type="hidden" name="par_code" value="F6aBYrq5wG" />
            <textarea class="text_cmt" name="text_cmt" placeholder="Reply to Guest"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Reply" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div name="children" id="children">
        <form action="edit.php" method="post" enctpye="" id="edit">
            <textarea class="text_cmt" name="text_cmt"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password to edit" id="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
        </form>
        <div class="child" name="gr425g4"><span class="author">hhhh</span><br />
            reeeeee<br />
            <span class="date">Posted: Sep 23, 2015 | 00:00:00</span><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="comment" name="TsA9y9hdvZ"><span class="author">Guest</span><br />
    kkkk<br />
    <span class="date">Posted: Sep 26, 2015 | 16:00:39</span><br />
    <span class="replies">[+] 1 replies</span><span class="replies">Reply</span>
    <div class="delete_wrapper">
        <form action="delete.php" method="post" enctpye="" class="form_delete">
            <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password to delete" id="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </form>
        <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="replytopic" name="send" />
        <button class="button2">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete_button">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div id="reply">
        <form class="reply" action="reply.php" method="post" enctpye="" name="new_comment">
            <input type="hidden" name="par_code" value="TsA9y9hdvZ" />
            <textarea class="text_cmt" name="text_cmt" placeholder="Reply to Guest"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Reply" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div name="children" id="children">
        <form action="edit.php" method="post" enctpye="" id="edit">
            <textarea class="text_cmt" name="text_cmt"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password to edit" id="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
        </form>
        <div class="child" name="ftdre76igu"><span class="author">kkkk</span><br />
            reply<br />
            <span class="date">Posted: Sep 16, 2015 | 00:00:00</span><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for , thanks a lot now i got it , I made the big mistake to use same-name id values.. and I'm sorry for my messy code I fix it. Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: Did you try my jsFiddle? Is that what you are looking for?